# RxJava .toblocking.tosingle() not returning at all

Tags: parallel-processing, rx-java, observable

I am trying to do parallel calls to two different REST services which returns different type of response. So I have used `observable.zip(...).toBlocking().single()` but it never returns at all.

Here is what I am doing ...

1. Trying to make parallel calls to different services using rx zip

Services I am trying to call
1. orderInfo
2. billInfo

```
    @Service
    public class ParallelServiceCallImpl {
    ...//var declaration ...

        Observable<OrderInfoResponse> getOrderInfoRsp(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
        return Observable.create((rx.Subscriber <? super OrderInfoResponse> s) -> {
        OrderInfoResponse ordrInfo = orderComponent.getOrderDetails(serviceRequest); // this component calls to end service
        });
    }

    Observable<BillInfoResponse> getBillInfoRsp(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
        return Observable.create((rx.Subscriber <? super BillInfoResponse> s) -> {
        BillInfoResponse billInfo = billInfoComponent.getBillingDetails(serviceRequest); // this component calls to end service
        });
    }


    public ServiceEndResponse getServiceBillFinance(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
        Observable<OrderInfoResponse> orderObservable = getOrderInfoRsp(serviceRequest);
        Observable<BillInfoResponse> billObservable = getBillInfoRsp(serviceRequest);
        Observable<ServiceEndResponse> responseObservable = Observable.zip(
            orderObservable,
            billObservable,
            (ordrInfo, billInfo) -> {
                ServiceEndResponse serviceEndResponse = serviceMapper.endResponseMapper(ordrInfo, billInfo);
                return serviceEndResponse;
            }
        );

        ServiceEndResponse serviceResponse = responseObservable.toBlocking().single();  // Not getting response 
        return serviceResponse;

    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing here, why it is not returning the `serviceResponse`

#### Added one more

I want to add one more to the above ...
I have `getProducts` method in my `ProductComponent` which calls `ProductInfo` service parallelly for all `productIds`

```
    public List<ProductsInfo> getProducts(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, List<String> productIds)   {
        List<ProductsInfo> lstProductInfo = new ArrayList<ProductsInfo>();
        List<Observable<ProductsInfo>> lstPrd = new ArrayList<Observable<ProductsInfo>>(productIds.size());
        for (String prdID : productIds) {
            Observable<ProductsInfo> prd = getProductObservable(serviceRequest, prdID); //Observable
            lstPrd.add(prd);
        }
        Iterable<Observable<ProductsInfo>> iterable = (Iterable<Observable<ProductsInfo>>)lstPrd;
        List<ProductsInfo> listofProd = Observable.zip(iterable, new FuncN<List<ProductsInfo>>(){
            public List<ProductsInfo> call(Object...args)   {
                for (Object arg : args) { lstProductInfo.add((ProductsInfo)arg);}
                return lstProductInfo;
            }
        }).toBlocking().single();
        return lstProductInfo;  
    }       
    //Create and Return Observable
    private Observable<ProductsInfo> getProductObservable(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String productId ) {
    return Observable.create((rx.Subscriber<? super ProductsInfo> s) -> {
        ProductsInfo prdct = getProduct(serviceRequest, productId);
        s.onNext(prdct);
        s.onCompleted();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    }
    //Call End Service
    private ProductsInfo getProduct(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String productId)    {
        serviceRequest.setProductID(productId);
        //service invocation
        svcResponse = getProductEndPoint.getProducts(serviceRequest);//**********/
        ProductsInfo product = serviceMapper.productMapper(svcResponse);
        return product;
    }
```

I want to make parallel call  to `ProductComponent.getProducts(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, List<String> productIds)` along with above 2 services .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `create(OnSubscribe)`, backpressure and unsubscription can be tricky to honour. However, when you did use `create` you didn't emit any items to the subscriber `s` so the single item never arrives.

Instead of `create` use `fromCallable`:

```
Observable<BillInfoResponse> getBillInfoRsp(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> 
        billInfoComponent.getBillingDetails(serviceRequest));
}
```

Then proceed with the `zip` as you were doing. If the observables represent network calls you may also want to add `.timeout` to the observable for a network call so that if the call hangs you fail early.

In terms of running network calling Observables in parallel use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` or `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(ExecutorService))` on the individual observables.

For example, to zip `a` and `b` and `c` in parallel:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.io();
a
 .zipWith(b.subscribeOn(scheduler))
 .zipWith(c.subscribeOn(scheduler))
 .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dave it worked , I am newly trying rxJava, All I implemented till now is sequential calls to multiple services and parallel calls to single service with multiple values. Please also suggest me on 2nd point, which I added. Thanks.